# Schedule reports in Pentaho user console

Tags: email, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

How to schedule reports in `Pentaho User Console`.
Also let me know how to email scheduled reports particular address in 
`Pentaho User Console`.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I am using Pentaho user console 6.1 version(Community version)
I had done R&D for same which showed me to go to Browse File-->Select report name-->Schedule(I am not able to find option such as schedule).

Comment: @SwapnilSolanki : did you find a solution ? I cannot find the schedule action in browse file section on pentaho 9. Is it an enterprise edition feature ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to add Email Functionality in Pentaho user console, for that you have to use pentaho data integration, what i will suggest is use pentaho data integration, run the report using PDI, schedule a job and add email step and send the report to specified email address.